# Updating Site.master control using CodeBehind from a different control's click event

Tags: c#, .net, master-pages

I am working on an AJAX site feature that when a user clicks a button certain things on the page update.  The issue I am running into is that the button is located in a specific control that only shows on certain pages and some of the information I need to update is located in the Site.master file.  Here's an idea of what's happening:

**The Site.master code I wish to be updated upon button clicking.** This code is in the header of every page, but only certain pages should be able to update it.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:HyperLink
          ID="Items" runat="server"
          EnableViewState="False"
          NavigateUrl="/Destination.aspx"
          Text="0 items"
          updatemode="Conditional" />
       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**The button in a separate control (Items.ascx).** This only shows on certain pages.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateItems" eventname="Click" />
     </Triggers>
     <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button runat="server" 
              OnClick="UpdateItems" 
              Text="Update Items" 
              class="update-items" 
              ID="UpdateItems" 
              name="UpdateItems" 
              type="submit">
         </asp:Button>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**And the method that runs when the button is clicked (Items.ascx.cs).** When clicked I would like for this to update the Items hyperlink in the first codeblock. This code only shows on certain pages.

```
protected void UpdateItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          UpdateItems.Text = "Done!";
          // can't use Items.Text = "1" or similar due to this being a separate control
    }
```

When I click the button, the text successfully changes to "Done!" which means the event is firing off just fine. The issue is that I am not sure how to update the Items hyperlink in the Site.master file. I've searched numerous different ideas and have ultimately come up empty.

**I want to note that this is an update to an already existing website so the location of these controls are not able to be moved easily or possibly at all due to how they effect the layout and where they are in the layout of the web page.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix mistype on `Site.master`: move `updatemode` attribute from hyperlink to UpdatePanel tag. Next, there are two approaches.
A. Set `UpdateMode="Always"` on `site.master`. I hope hyperlink navigateUrl and text are not hardcoded.
B. In your control code

```
protected void UpdateItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          UpdateItems.Text = "Done!";
          var mp = this.Page.MasterPage;
          var up = mp.FindControl("Panel11");
          var hl = up.FindControl("Items");
          //do something with hl
          up.Update(); //if updateMode="Conditional"
          // can't use Items.Text = "1" or similar due to this being a separate control
    }
```

Comment: So I used the option where updatemode is set to Conditional and I'm getting an error:

CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'MasterPage'

Comment: Sorry, `this.Page.Master`